# Morphline Read one big file

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, solrcloud, morphline

I have a Hive table that i am trying to index into SolrCloud using morphline, however, the data behind the Hive table is ONE big file 20GB that morphline is taking a long time to process.

Instead of running multiple mappers and reducers, there can only be 1 mapper running, probably due to the fact that we have only one file.

```
yarn jar /opt/<path>/search-mr-1.0.0-cdh5.5.1-job.jar \
org.apache.solr.hadoop.MapReduceIndexerTool \
--morphline-file morphlines.conf \
--output-dir hdfs://<outputdir> \
--zk-host node1.datafireball.com:2181/solr \
--collection <collectionname> \
--input-list <filewherethedatais> \
--mappers 6
```

And it still kicked out only 1 job... and this is taking forever, can anyone shed some light on this?

Resources You might find helpful:

1. [Cloudera Mapreduce Batch Index into Solrcloud](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/archive/search/1-3-0/Cloudera-Search-User-Guide/csug_mapreduceindexertool.html?scroll=csug_topic_6_1)
2. [Kitesdk which morphline belongs to.](http://kitesdk.org/docs/1.1.0/morphlines/morphlines-reference-guide.html#readCSV)

Comment: Your file isn't splittable? If it were, there wouldn't be one mapper

Comment: @cricket_007, it is one big file, and standard hive table, each line is one record and columns are delimited by u'\0001'. I assume that is something pretty straightforward and morphline doesn't want to split it as default.

Comment: So sounds like the Hive table was defined with `fields terminated by '\u0001'`? I don't know why it would only one file, though